# passing record to a view using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using .NET 4.0, MVC3 and entity framework 4.0

I need to pass a database record of type "statement" to a view. The code to fetch the record is as below:

```
public ActionResult pdfStatement(string InvoiceNumber)

{

            ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[1];

            parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("InvoiceNumber", InvoiceNumber);

            return View(_db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Statement>("uspInvoiceStatement", parameters));            
        }
```

where "uspInvoiceStatement" is my stored procedure used to fetch "statement"

I have created a strongly typed view which receives the "statement"

```
< % @ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage < InvoiceSearch.Models.Statement >" %>
```

When i run the application i get an exception saying

```
    "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[InvoiceSearch.Models.Statement]',
 but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'InvoiceSearch.Models.Statement'.
```

Help me to escape from this trouble.
 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is surprisingly helpful - it tells you, you are sending ObjectResult<Statement> to the view asi viewmodel, while you should send Statement.

Your _db.ExecuteFunction always returns ObjectResult<Statement>, so you need to take Statement from it, like this :

```
var statementResult = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Statement>("uspInvoiceStatement", parameters);
var statement = statementResult.SingleOrDefault();
if (statement != null)
{
    return View(statement); // isnt that nicer when you can see what your viewmodel is?
}
else
{
    return View("NotFound");
}
```